# sqlite android backup restore example code

Tags: android, sqlite, database-backups, android-backup-service

I'm trying to teach myself how to use Android's `BackupRestore` service to back up my app's sqlite database, but I can't find any example code on how to properly extend `BackupAgent` or `BackupAgentHelper`, so I'm a little lost...

I looked at  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/ExampleAgent.html but am uncertain as to how to apply this example to backing up a sqlite db file...

Does anyone have any example code for backing up an entire sqlite database (the `onRestore` and `onBackup` methods), or any ideas about resources (other than the `BackupRestore` docs - I've looked through those extensively and they're difficult for me to understand).

Answer (score 0):

This example code seem's pretty documented. Have you looked through this yet?

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/BackupRestoreActivity.html

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific-- I need to know how to extend BackupAgent.. similar to http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/ExampleAgent.html but for a sqlite db file.

Comment: Did you ever find an example or succeed at backing up/restoring SQLite db?